# get all Materials based from UUID from two variables

Tags: php, laravel-5

so, I have `$patient_banner` that returns this:

```
[
    "3d078010-e24b-11e8-ab1d-2b077991ec5f",
    "64095f20-e25c-11e8-a2de-171e70f82e0f",
    "6b3ea0e0-e24b-11e8-8316-13a0f1f91303",
    "d9b275b0-e249-11e8-b8ce-fd92c15325d5",
    "7535baf0-e23e-11e8-8297-f50579ab9646"
]
```

and I have `$material_ids` that returns this:

```
[
    "65903500-9fe2-11e8-9dc3-9d0a219835de",
    "67e52880-d74f-11e8-921e-8f389ce79225"
]
```

and I am executing this code:

```
$material  = new Material;

$materials  = $material->whereIn(
   'uuid',
   [$material_ids, $patient_banner]
);
```

---

What I want to happen is that, it would return the Materials that has the UUIDS from both `$patient_banner` and `$material_ids`so it should return 7 materials, but what I am getting are only 2 materials who are in the `$material_ids`. What should I do to get 7 materials from 2 different variables?

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya yep. I was waiting for 8 minutes to be able to accept the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can merge the two arrays into one, using [`array_merge`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php):

```
$materials  = $material->whereIn(
   'uuid',
   array_merge($material_ids, $patient_banner)
);
```

---

Your current attempt `[$material_ids, $patient_banner]` will not merge the two arrays. Instead it would create an array of arrays, like below:

```
[
 [0] => [
         "3d078010-e24b-11e8-ab1d-2b077991ec5f",
         "64095f20-e25c-11e8-a2de-171e70f82e0f",
         "6b3ea0e0-e24b-11e8-8316-13a0f1f91303",
         "d9b275b0-e249-11e8-b8ce-fd92c15325d5",
         "7535baf0-e23e-11e8-8297-f50579ab9646"
        ], 
 [1] => [
         "65903500-9fe2-11e8-9dc3-9d0a219835de",
         "67e52880-d74f-11e8-921e-8f389ce79225"
        ]
]
```